# Chart.js Doughnut chart not properly work

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am trying to use chart.js Doughnut chart. my JSON data is properl fetch from data base.
But at the fill time of value chart will not display. If i am pasting example code static then its showing proper data.

```
function playerPrel2Res(qID){
    var tmp="#playerVoteId"+qID;
    var lab=$(tmp).text();
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : contextPath + '/common/playerPredCounter.action', //contextPath for dynamic
        dataType : 'json',
        data : {predictionID:qID},
        success : function(data) {
            var id=new Array();
            var name=new Array();

            for ( var i = 0; i < data.properties.length; i++) {
                id[i]= data.properties[i].id;
                name[i]= data.properties[i].name;
            }
            alert("hi...");
            var doughnutData = [
                {
                    value: id[0],
                    color:"#F7464A",
                    highlight: "#FF5A5E",
                    label: name[0]
                },
                {
                    value: id[1],
                    color: "#46BFBD",
                    highlight: "#5AD3D1",
                    label: name[1]
                },
                {
                    value: id[2],
                    color: "#FDB45C",
                    highlight: "#FFC870",
                    label: name[2]
                },
            ];

        window.onload = function(){
            var ctx = document.getElementById('playerChartArea').getContext("2d");
            alert(ctx +"path");
            window.myDoughnut = new Chart(ctx).Doughnut(doughnutData, {responsive : true});
        };              

        }
    });
}
```

this will not display any out put but i write like this static then show chart

```
var doughnutData = [
                {
                    value: id[0].val(),
                    color:"#F7464A",
                    highlight: "#FF5A5E",
                    label: name[0].val()
                },
                {
                    value: 50,
                    color: "#46BFBD",
                    highlight: "#5AD3D1",
                    label: "Green"
                },
                {
                    value: 100,
                    color: "#FDB45C",
                    highlight: "#FFC870",
                    label: "Yellow"
                },
                {
                    value: 40,
                    color: "#949FB1",
                    highlight: "#A8B3C5",
                    label: "Grey"
                },
                {
                    value: 120,
                    color: "#4D5360",
                    highlight: "#616774",
                    label: "Dark Grey"
                }
            ];

        window.onload = function(){
            var ctx = document.getElementById('playerChartArea').getContext("2d");
            alert(ctx +"path");
            window.myDoughnut = new Chart(ctx).Doughnut(doughnutData, {responsive : true});
        };
```

and one thing is that my alert is not display for `ctx`
Please help me out.

Comment: I have the same problem. If the value is from database, doughnut chart not showing, I print_r the array, the value was correct. But if I set the static value, it showing.  Anyone please....

Comment: Hey.. I successfully displaying the Doughnut by using `intval($value)` for the value. I am generating the data array using PHP. Maybe you can do the same thing in your Javascript by getting the integer value of the value. I do not now how to do it in Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have done by using this just do this, i'm pasting my code

```
var doughnutData="";
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : contextPath + '/common/action', //contextPath for dynamic
        dataType : 'json',
        data : {predictionID:oID},
        success : function(data) {
            var id=new Array();
            var name=new Array();

            for ( var i = 0; i < data.properties.length; i++) {
                id[i]= data.properties[i].id;
                name[i]= data.properties[i].name;
            }

             doughnutData = [
                {
                    value: id[0],
                    color:"#F7464A",
                    highlight: "#FF5A5E",
                    label: name[0]
                },
                {
                    value: id[1],
                    color: "#46BFBD",
                    highlight: "#5AD3D1",
                    label: name[1]
                },
                {
                    value: id[2],
                    color: "#FDB45C",
                    highlight: "#FFC870",
                    label: name[2]
                },
                {
                    value: id[3],
                    color: "#949FB1",
                    highlight: "#A8B3C5",
                    label: name[3]
                },
                {
                    value: id[4],
                    color: "#4D5360",
                    highlight: "#616774",
                    label: name[4]
                }
            ];
            var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
            window.myDoughnut = new Chart(ctx).Doughnut(doughnutData, {responsive : true});
        }
    });
```

so just declare doughnutData variable global and remove `windows.load` function and just remain internal code. that's it