# Chart.Js Doughnut not calculating JSON data properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

When using static data, the Doughnut chart appear perfectly, example:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'includes/stats.php?show',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) 
        {
            console.log(response['CARS']); //I see 2
            console.log(response['MOTORS']); //I see 0
            console.log(response['BOATS']); //I see 0
            var autoData = [
                {
                    value: 2,
                    color: "#4286f4",
                    highlight: "#4d6fa5",
                    label: "Cars"
                },
                {
                    value: 0,
                    color: "#3fe276",
                    highlight: "#51a36d",
                    label: "Motor Homes"
                },
                {
                    value: 0,
                    color: "#bde234",
                    highlight: "#87964e",
                    label: "Boats"
                }
            ];
            var ctx = document.getElementById("onChart").getContext("2d");
            var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx).Doughnut(autoData);                 
        }
});
```

I'm doing the JSON call, but on the callback, I'm filling autoData variable with static data [2, 0, 0], this way the chart appears and calculate 100% for "Cars", because it is the only with some value (2), others are 0's...
When I do:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'includes/stats.php?show',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) 
        {
            console.log(response['CARS']); //I see 2
            console.log(response['MOTORS']); //I see 0
            console.log(response['BOATS']); //I see 0
            var autoData = [
                {
                    value: response['CARS'],
                    color: "#4286f4",
                    highlight: "#4d6fa5",
                    label: "Cars"
                },
                {
                    value: response['MOTORS'],
                    color: "#3fe276",
                    highlight: "#51a36d",
                    label: "Motor Homes"
                },
                {
                    value: response['BOATS'],
                    color: "#bde234",
                    highlight: "#87964e",
                    label: "Boats"
                }
            ];
            var ctx = document.getElementById("onChart").getContext("2d");
            var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx).Doughnut(autoData);                 
        }
});
```

I get just what looks like a 2% slice of the chart filled... What's happening here?

Comment: Try and see if this link helps you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25665019/chart-js-doughnut-chart-not-properly-work

Comment: I saw this question already, and I tried the solution accepted, but no success (put the data variable as global)... Now I got back to the question as you asked me, and I saw a comment, where a person said he used "intval" from PHP to make the array... I tried that, and it worked! :) I will answer this in the question here. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I was constructing the JSON from PHP, something like:

```
    $data = $autoQuery->fetch_array();
    $autoData = array('CARS' => $data['CARS'],
                    'MOTORS' => $data['MOTORS'],
                    'BOATS' => $data['BOATS']);
    echo json_encode($autoData);
```

This wasn't working. When I put intval() before each $data variable, it worked!